# nodejs jenkins build downloading all dependent packages

Tags: node.js, build, package.json

I am trying to automatically build nodejs module via jenkins.  My github is connected to jenkins, so as soon as code is pushed a new build is generated.
I can see when build is generated node_modules directory contains all packages which are dependencies in package.json.

I have three doubts regarding this:

1. Why creation of build requires to download all dependent
   packages.When user will install that module via

   ```
   npm install
   ```

   then whatever pacakages are present in package.json will get
   downloaded again to his client machine.
2. Is it good idea to not to download dependent packages while build creation?
3. Can we do something to stop downloading of packages during build creation?

Comment: What do you mean by "build?" Are you referring to actually compiling a node addon (e.g. using a C++ compiler), or are you referring to the act of combining multiple javascript source files into one, or something else?

Comment: build is like using make command to create bundle of nodejs which internally runs package.json and after that it creates bundle